# How To: Dynamic links from the_author_meta WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a directory with custom user fields created in MemberPress.

My markup works perfectly in displaying the data, but I need to link to the URL expressed in a Website field I've created. I'm getting a live link, but the containing website URL is prefixing the actual URL.

Current link - `http://mysite.org/directories/manufacturers/www.zehnderamerica.com`

Should be - `http://www.zehnderamerica.com`

This is where I'm stumped:

```
<a href="<?php echo the_author_meta('mepr_website', $user->ID);?>"><?php the_author_meta('mepr_website', $user->ID);?></a>
```

My full markup to display the user data:

```
<?php
                $args = array (
                    'exclude' => array(1, 3, 1143, 1364),
                    'role' => 'subscriber',
                );

                $blogusers = get_users( $args );
                foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
                    $profield = get_the_author_meta('mepr_manufacturersupplier_only', $user->ID);
                    if ($profield == "mechanical") {
                        echo '<tr class="membersList"><td>' 
                                                . $user->user_firstname . ' ' 
                                                . $user->user_lastname . ' ' 
                                                . $user->user_url 
                               . '</td>'; ?>
                            <td><?php the_author_meta('mepr_organizationcompany', $user->ID);?><br /><a href="<?php echo the_author_meta('mepr_website', $user->ID);?>"><?php the_author_meta('mepr_website', $user->ID);?></a></td>
                            <td><?php the_author_meta('mepr_phone', $user->ID);?></td>
                            <td><?php the_author_meta('user_email', $user->ID);?></td>
                            <td><?php the_author_meta('mepr_certifications', $user->ID);?></td>
                        <?php echo '</tr>';?><?php 
                        $args=array(
                          'author' => $user->ID,
                          'post_type' => 'post',
                          'post_status' => 'publish',
                          'posts_per_page' => -1,
                          'caller_get_posts'=> 1
                        );
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prepend http:// to the front of your href URL.

```
<a href="http://<?php echo the_author_meta('mepr_website', $user->ID);?>"><?php the_author_meta('mepr_website', $user->ID);?></a>
```

If you're sure http:// is never entered with the website, this is fine. Otherwise, you'll want to do some checking on the URL first to see if it's present and only add it if it's not.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas, I overlooked it.